# Collapsing a Factor To Create A New Variable

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm getting a little confused on the difference between a factor and new variable in tidyverse. I'm trying to create a new variable based on whether a person's newspaper is for or against a policy ( the EU in this case).  I've tried to use `mutate` and `fct_collapse` as shown here.

```
joint%>% 
  mutate(grouped = fct_collapse(Paper_Before, Pro_Eu = c("grauniad","Independent", "FT"), 
                               Anti_Eu = c("Telegraph", "Daily Mail"), 
                               Times ="Times", 
                               Rest = c("Sun", "Others", "Daily Mirror", "Daily Star", "Daily Express")))



 grouped_newspapers <- joint %>%
                        select(grouped, EU_Vote_Intent_Before, EU_Vote_Intent_After)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

[My data can be found with this link.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/27671y6dczs0ipr/here.csv?dl=0)

To be clear, I've grouped the 10 different  papers of Papers_before into 4 new categories but instead of tidyverse recognising this as a new column it sees it only as a factor: I think I have a misunderstanding of the concept basically!

Comment: This is very difficult without a sample of your data. Help us help you, edit your question and add the result of `dput(head(joint))`.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. The code in the question did what you want it to do when I tried it with your data, with a new variable called "grouped" with Pro_Eu, Anti_Eu, Times and Rest as specified.